# how to inflate a layout into a linear layout in expandible list adapter

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

i want to inflate a layout, on linear layout of expandable list's item, on certain condition. following is the code(written in getChildView()) I'm trying for inflating. the scenario is if user selects an item with a subitems detail and item is not already in the cart, there should be a row added below the item, showing its sub items detail. its giving error on addview().

```
 if (menuItem.hasSubItems() && !cart.contains(menuItem))
        {
            View inflated = null;
            if (inflated == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                //to get the MainLayout
                inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_items_detail_row, null);
                holder.subitemContainer.addView(inflated);
            }

        }
```

here i'm binding the view in view holder

```
   public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
        this.rootView = view;
        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
        tvPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvprice1);
        tvCounter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemCouter);
        moreInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moreInfo);
        roomService_menu_img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.roomService_menu_img);
        addView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgadd);
        removeView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgDelete);
        subitemContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.subitemContainer);
```

but i'm having this error in log

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:715)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                           at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                           at com.kaimeramedia.mobilexp.modules.locationservices.adapters.RoomServiceCartAdapter.getChildView(RoomServiceCartAdapter.java:210)
                                                                           at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2396)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1889)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:713)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1376)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1675)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2200)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16000)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5228)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2101)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5873)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

this is the getchildview() code

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ItemViewHolder holder;
    final RoomServiceMenuItem menuItem = (RoomServiceMenuItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowroomservice_new, null);
        holder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ItemViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    String strName = menuItem.getName();
    if (strName.contains("\\n")) {
        String[] parts = Pattern.compile("\\n", Pattern.LITERAL).split(strName);
        strName = parts[0] + "\n" + parts[1];
    }
    holder.tvTitle.setText(strName);
    holder.tvDesc.setText(menuItem.getDescription());
    holder.tvPrice.setText("$ " + Utils.formatMoney(menuItem.getPrice()));

    CartItem cartItem = cart.findByMenuItem(menuItem);
    int quantity = cartItem != null ? cartItem.getQuantity() : 0;
    holder.tvCounter.setVisibility(quantity <= 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));

    holder.addView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check if this item already exist in cart if it has sub-items
            boolean cartItemAlreadyAdded = cart.contains(menuItem);
            if (menuItem.hasSubItems() && !cartItemAlreadyAdded) {
                // use need to select its sub-item first
                cartListener.onClickShowSubItems(menuItem);

                return;
            }
            // User has this item in his cart so just increase the quantity with same sub-items
            cart.add(new CartItem(menuItem));
            int q = cart.findByMenuItem(menuItem).getQuantity();
            onCartChange(holder, menuItem, q);
            cartListener.onItemAdded(menuItem, q);
        }
    });
    if (menuItem.hasSubItems() && !cart.contains(menuItem))
    {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //to get the MainLayout
            View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_items_detail_row, null);
            holder.subitemContainer.addView(inflated);

    }

    holder.removeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cart.contains(menuItem.getId())) {
                cart.remove(new CartItem(menuItem));
                CartItem cartItem = cart.findByMenuItem(menuItem);
                int q = cartItem != null ? cartItem.getQuantity() : 0;
                onCartChange(holder, menuItem, q);
                if (q <= 0) menuItem.clearSubItemsSelection();
                cartListener.onItemRemoved(menuItem, q);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cartListener.onClickMoreInfo(menuItem);
        }
    });

    if (menu != null) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(menu.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.roomService_menu_img);
    }

    if (menuItem.hasSubItems()) {
        holder.rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cartListener.onClickShowSubItems(menuItem);
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
```

and this is the xml i want to infate the layout into.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_2sdp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cartCounter"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp">


            <com.kaimeramedia.mobilexp.components.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/roomService_menu_img"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemCouter"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roomservice_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/exp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cartCounter"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cartCounter"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rel"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Offer Title"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="desc"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/moreInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_more_info"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                    android:paddingRight="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvprice1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="$ 0.0"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#e3e0dd"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgadd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/plusicon"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgadd"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@color/orange">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/plusicon"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:id="@+id/subitemContainer"
           android:layout_below="@+id/rel"></LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your RoomServiceCartAdapter.getChildView code and xml file.

Comment: i've edited. please check